Beer clip packaging
I am trying to model the beer pack illustrated in the picture. I am new to blender, and have been working through tutorials, but not sure how what I have learnt applies to this type of modelling in particular.
I have created a Boolean cut for the holes, but I am struggling to create the “teeth” in such a way that I can then model them to fit around a can that I have already created.
Could someone offer any advice on how to create this feature please?
Kind regards,
Justin


This website is best for asking help for how to solve a specific problem, not necessarily asking for broad suggestions or if someone can do the whole thing for you. This is a relatively simple shape, so why not just try modeling it and see what happens? If you have problems while modeling that then come here and ask how to solve that specific problem.

Maybe I didn’t make it clear then. My problem is that I have spent a lot of time trying to model the clip “teeth” after a Boolean operation. It is leading to geometry that I can’t modify etc and have spent many hours already trying to solve

Show an image of what you have so far and a simplified Blend file would help too.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Its half a sphere disconnected with a plane

Create a cyilinder, extrude upwards, select the edge ring and press V to rip these edges:

In the Transform Pivot Point panel choose Individual Origins, select the top edges and scale down the edges:

Model the rest:


We do not know what you have done so far and what your result looks like. I will make an assumption which might fit your model or at least you might be able to apply it to your model in one way or the other. Of course I expect you to have the Boolean modifier applied already so that the holes are editable meshes.
When you have a hole around a can, select the vertices which are the boundary of the hole. Press E Z to extrude them upwards as far as you like (my example might not fit your reference, sorry).

Make sure to switch the Transform Pivot Point to Individual Origins.

Then press S to scale the top edge down so that it fits snug to the can without intersecting it.

Now Alt+M and choose Split > Faces & Edges by Vertices.

Again press S to scale the top edges. Since they are split now and are scaled on individual pivots, the gaps between them get larger.


Despite my poor explanation this worked great, thank you. Very clear and was a first time fix

@JustinMcCree Then you might consider accepting one of our answers? Both should work for you. See: What should I do when someone answers my question?
